# Three js orbit control set angles

Tags: three.js

I'm making a 3D globe in three js with orbit control and I would like to be able to set the camera over a specific GPS coordinate.

To to that I would need to set the polar angle and the azimuth angle of the camera. However, orbit control only contain methods for GETTING those angles (`getPolarAngle` and `getAzimuthAngle`).

How can I set those angle then ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can use `THREE.Spherical()` and set the position of a camera with [`.setFromSpherical()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3.setFromSpherical) method of `THREE.Vector3()`.